# Is the content of a performance appraisal admissible content during an interview/on a resume

Tags: interviewing, resume, ethics

Is it acceptable to reference (or possibly provide copies of) performance appraisals during an interview (or as part of a resume), if one has gotten especially sterling reviews during performance appraisal (which mention distinct achievements from the perspective of management)?

Answer (score 4):

As far as providing copies goes: My employer declares anything personnel-related company confidential, requiring a manager's approval to release outside the company. Check your company's policies.

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead and mention it. As long as there wan't some sort of contractual nondisclosure agreement, it seems not only permissible, but a fabulous idea.

**Of course a potential new employer wants to know if you've been doing really well** at your previous job - it's a fabulous reason to employ you themselves!!